# Order reciprocity

Tags: number-theory

Let $p, q$ be distinct prime numbers. Is there any relation between order of $p$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{\times}$ and order of $q$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$? I wrote a program with SAGE and here's a list of some results:

(3, 5, 4, 2)
(3, 7, 6, 1)
(3, 11, 5, 2)
(3, 13, 3, 1)
(3, 17, 16, 2)
(3, 19, 18, 1)
(3, 23, 11, 2)
(3, 29, 28, 2)
(5, 7, 6, 4)
(5, 11, 5, 1)
(5, 13, 4, 4)
(5, 17, 16, 4)
(5, 19, 9, 2)
(5, 23, 22, 4)
(5, 29, 14, 2)
(7, 11, 10, 3)
(7, 13, 12, 2)
(7, 17, 16, 6)
(7, 19, 3, 6)
(7, 23, 22, 3)
(7, 29, 7, 1)
(11, 13, 12, 10)
(11, 17, 16, 10)
(11, 19, 3, 10)
(11, 23, 22, 1)
(11, 29, 28, 10)
(13, 17, 4, 6)
(13, 19, 18, 12)
(13, 23, 11, 6)
(13, 29, 14, 3)
(17, 19, 9, 8)
(17, 23, 22, 16)
(17, 29, 4, 16)
(19, 23, 22, 9)
(19, 29, 28, 18)
(23, 29, 7, 11)

Here the quadruple stands for $(p, q, ord_{q}p, ord_{p}q)$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a weak relationship implied by quadratic reciprocity.

Let $p$ and $q$ be odd primes, and let $a$ be the order of $p$ modulo $q$ and let $b$ be the order of $q$ modulo $p$.  It's always true that $a$ divides $q-1$ and $b$ divides $p-1$.  However, $p$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$ if and only if $a$ divides $(q-1)/2$; similarly for $b$.  Thus, by quadratic reciprocity, if either $p$ or $q$ is $1$ mod $4$, then one of two things occurs:

- $a$ divides $(q-1)/2$, and $b$ divides $(p-1)/2$, as in the case of $(5,19,9,2)$; or
- $a$ does not divide $(q-1)/2$, and $b$ does not divide $(p-1)/2$, as with $(5,17,16,4)$.

In other words, $a$ and $b$ either *both do* or *both do not* contain the largest power of $2$ dividing $(q-1)/2$ or $(p-1)/2$, respectively.

If neither $p$ nor $q$ is $1$ mod $4$, then neither of those cases occur; instead the one of the two remaining possibilities occurs:

- $a$ divides $(q-1)/2$, but $b$ does not divide $(p-1)/2$, as with $(3,23,11,2)$; or
- $a$ does not divide $(q-1)/2$, but $b$ divides $(p-1)/2$, as with $(3,19,18,1)$.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to show that there are infinitely many pair of primes $(p, q)$ such that $ord_{p}(q) = q-1$ and $ord_{q}(p) = q-1$? It seems true with experiments.

Comment: I think that follows from Heath-Brown's remarkable 1987 result on Artin's conjecture. It implies that at least one of the Fermat primes 5, 17 and 257 is a primitive root (and thus a quadratic non-residue) for an infinite number of primes.  By quadratic reciprocity, each such prime is a non-residue of the Fermat prime; but for Fermat primes, every non-residue is automatically a primitive root.

Answer (score 2):

For two distinct primes $p,q$, you ask for "any relation" between $ord_q(p)$ in ${\mathbf F_q}^*$ and $ord_p(q)$ in ${\mathbf F_p}^*$. @FredH gave you "a weak relationship based on quadratic reciprocity". Actually  a more complete *theoretical* relationship can in principle be expressed in terms of "symbols" in CFT which generalize the Legendre symbol. For these, I'll refer conveniently to Cassels-Fröhlich's ANT, more precisely, at the end of the book, to **Exercise 1: The Power Residue symbol (Legendre, Gauss, et al.)** and **Exercise 2: The Norm Residue symbol (Hilbert, Hasse)**. Supposing $p,q$ odd for simplicity, your question can be reformulated in terms of powers : since ${\mathbf F_q}^*$ (resp. ${\mathbf F_p}^*$) is  cyclic, the determination of $ord_q(p)$ (resp. $ord_p(q)$) amounts to that of the minimal $n_q$ (resp. $n_p$) s.t. $p$ mod $q$ (resp. $q$ mod $p$) is an $n_q$-th (resp. $n_p$-th) power in ${\mathbf F_q}^*$ (resp. ${\mathbf F_p}^*$). Note that $p\nmid n_q$ and $q\nmid n_p$.

1) Let us recall *a minima* the definition and main properties of the power residue symbol. Consider a finite extension $K_v/\mathbf Q_p$ (where $v$ is the additive valuation of the field), with residual field $k_v$ of cardinal $Nv$ (the norm of the maximal ideal $P_v$ of $v$). Suppose that $K_v$ contains the group $\mu_n$ of $n$-th roots of 1, with $p\nmid n$, and so $n\mid (Nv-1)$. Under our hypotheses, it's easy to show that $\mu_n(K_v) \cong \mu_n (k_v)$ by passing to the residue classes, and $ {k_v}^*/{{k_v}^*}^n \cong \mu_n (k_v)$ via $x\to x^{(Nv-1)/n}=Frob (\sqrt [n]x)/\sqrt [n]x$. For any unit $b$ of $K_v$, define the $n$-th power residue symbol ${(\frac bv)}_n$ to be the unique $n$-th root of 1 s.t. ${(\frac bv)}_n\equiv b^{(Nv-1)/n}$ mod $P_v$. Note that this is a generalized Euler criterion, and for $n=2$ one recovers the local Legendre symbol. The main property with concern to us is that ${(\frac bv)}_n=1$ iff $b\in {{K_v}^*}^n$, iff the residue class $\bar b \in {{k_v}^*}^n$. This applies to your problem on taking $K_v=\mathbf Q_p (\mu_n)$ and $b=q$. Then  ${(\frac qv)}_n=1$ iff $q$ mod $P_v$ is an $n$-th power in ${k_v}^*$. Yet, since $p\nmid n$, the extension $K_v/\mathbf Q_p$ is unramified, hence $k_v$ is a strict extension of $\mathbf F_p$ , so we have to compare ${{\mathbf F_p}^*}^n$ and ${{k_v}^*}^n$. This amounts to studying the natural map ${\mathbf F_p}^*/{{\mathbf F_p}^*}^n \to {({k_v}^*/{{k_v}^*}^n)}^G$, where $G=Gal(k_v/\mathbf F_p)$, or, because of the previous characterization of these quotients groups, the natural map $\mu_n(\mathbf F_p) \to {\mu_n (k_v)}^G$. This is an isomorphism, and we are done : ${(\frac qv)}_n=1$ iff $q$ mod $p$ is an $n$-th power in ${\mathbf F_p}^*$.

2) It remains to compute the power residue symbol ${(\frac bv)}_n$, or at least to characterize its triviality. There are sufficient conditions bearing on $v(b-1)$ to ensure the triviality of the symbol. But, with a view towards some reciprocity law, it's better to adopt a global-local point of view. From now on, $K$ is a number field containing $\mu_n$. In a first local step, consider the completion $K_v$ w.r.t. a $p$-adic valuation $v$, and for simplicity drop the index $n$ in the local symbol notations. Without further hypotheses, local CFT allows to define the Hilbert symbol $(b,a)_v$ (I don't recall the definition; see C-F, loc. cit.). If $v(b)=0=v(n)$ as before, but no condition on $v(a)$, it's known that ${(\frac bv)}^{v(a)}=(b,a)_v$, and the latter "tame" Hilbert symbol is explicit. Back to the global field, take $a,b\in K^*$ and define $(\frac ba)={\prod}_v {(\frac bv)}^{v(a)}$, the product bearing on all $v$ s.t. $v(b)=v(n)=0$. The power-reciprocity law then reads : $(\frac ba)(\frac ab)^{-1}={\prod}_v (b,a)_v$, the product bearing on all $v$ s.t. $v(a)=v(b)=v(n)=0$ (C-F, loc. cit.), but unfortunately the Hilbert symbols which appear here are *wild* symbols, for which explicit formulas are known only in particular cases. However this reciprocity law can be applied to your problem because the mentioned particular cases include cyclotomic fields ./.